# Confused about netbeans "Enable auto-scanning of sources" option

Tags: indexing, netbeans

I have started working on a large project (~100k files, C/C++), and I have imported this existing project into netbeans. I want to reduce netbeans's startup time, and I disabled this auto-scanning option under Options->Miscellaneous->Files. This has been frequently reported here on SO. I'm using NB v8.2, which I believe is the latest version that supports C++.

I notice that there is an option under Source->Scan for external changes, but this doesn't update the file indexing. Is this the intention?

I also noticed that there is another option at Project-name->right-click->Code Assistance->Parse project. What is the intention of this?

As a test, the following code snippet fails to index

```
1. MessageQueue max34460Queue(MSGQ_NAME_TO_MAX34460, MAX_MSG_SIZE, 10);
2. char buffer[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
3. int bytesReceived = max34460Queue.receive(buffer, STATUS_SEND_INTERVAL);
```

The symbol max34460Queue declared on line 1 is not recognised on line 3:
"Cannot open element max34460Queue"

Many thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Netbeans for C++ is stuck at v8.2. It seems that Apache have no intentions to keep this up to date. I have to assume that it will no longer be supported, and regretfully I have decided to move to Eclipse.